# Google maps url - map center

Tags: google-maps, url, coordinates, center

Sorry for the newbie question, but I am confident that someone can help me.

There is any possibility to keep the map centered on the green arrow when we open google maps through a link (e.g. https://maps.google.de/maps?q=10.404989,10.091751&z=4&t=k ), because when I zoom, it looses the focus on the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can get this working by dropping the `&ll` and `&spn` values in your URL and just using the `&sll` and `&sspn`.  In that way you're specifying the search origin lat long and span, but not giving the exact lat long (which the map will center on).  I think your `&ll` value is incorrect.

So this works :

https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=82-84+Brick+Lane,+London,+E1+6RL&aq=&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=82+Brick+Ln,+London+E1+6RL,+United+Kingdom&t=m&z=14&ll=51.533905,-0.104422&spn=0.008418,0.023378

But this doesn't :

https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=82-84+Brick+Lane,+London,+E1+6RL&aq=&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=82+Brick+Ln,+London+E1+6RL,+United+Kingdom&t=m&z=14&ll=51.533905,-0.104422&spn=0.008418,0.023378&ll=51.533905,-0.104422&spn=0.008418,0.023378